# jQuery preloader doesn't stop and won't transition to main page

Tags: jquery

I can't understand where the issue is, I have no errors in console neither. The page is just stuck on the loading screen and wouldn't redirect to the actual site

HTML for the preloader:

```
    <!--preloader-->
<div class="preloader js-preloader flex-center" id="preload">
  <div class="dots">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end preloader-->
```

CSS for the preloader:

```
    .flex-center {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #60D7A9;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.dots .dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-animation: dot-dot-dot 1.4s linear infinite;
  animation: dot-dot-dot 1.4s linear infinite;
}

.dots .dot:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

.dots .dot:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

@keyframes dot-dot-dot {
  0%, 60%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: initial;
      -ms-transform: initial;
        transform: initial;
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-25px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-25px);
        transform: translateY(-25px);
  }
}
```

jQuery Plugin: https://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Loader-Preloader-Plugin-jQuery-Preloadinator.html

Code for the plugin:

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.preloadinator = function(options) {
        'use strict';

        var settings = $.extend({
            scroll: false,
            minTime: 0,
            animation: 'fadeOut',
            animationDuration: 400,
            afterDisableScroll: function() {},
            afterEnableScroll: function() {},
            afterRemovePreloader: function() {}
        }, options),
        preloader = this,
        start = new Date().getTime();

        $.fn.preloadinator.disableScroll = function() {
            $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');

            if(typeof settings.afterDisableScroll == 'function') {
                settings.afterDisableScroll.call(this);
            }
        }

        $.fn.preloadinator.enableScroll = function() {
            $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');

            if(typeof settings.afterEnableScroll == 'function') {
                settings.afterEnableScroll.call(this);
            }
        }

        $.fn.preloadinator.removePreloader = function() {
            $(preloader)[settings.animation](settings.animationDuration, function() {
                if(settings.scroll === false) { 
                    $.fn.preloadinator.enableScroll(); 
                }
                if(typeof settings.afterRemovePreloader == 'function') {
                    settings.afterRemovePreloader.call(this);   
                }
            });
        }

        $.fn.preloadinator.minTimeElapsed = function() {
            var now = new Date().getTime(),
            elapsed = now - start;

            if(elapsed >= settings.minTime) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if(settings.scroll === false) { $.fn.preloadinator.disableScroll(); }

        $(window).on('load', function() {
            if($.fn.preloadinator.minTimeElapsed()) {
                $.fn.preloadinator.removePreloader();
            }
            else {
                var now = new Date().getTime(),
                elapsed = now - start;

                setTimeout($.fn.preloadinator.removePreloader, settings.minTime - elapsed);
            }
        });

        return this;
    }
}(jQuery));

$('.js-preloader').preloadinator();

$('.js-preloader').preloadinator({
      scroll:false,
      minTime: 2000,  
      animation: 'fadeOut',
      animationDuration: 400,
      afterEnableScroll: function() {},
      afterRemovePreloader: function() {},
    });
```

I've been looking for a solution for hours, can't seem to find anything. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, the plugin used here is just for showing the loading icon.

If you go to the link you shared above, you can see the callback functions, basically you have to add code there to redirect to another page.

[image]

Something like this

```
$('.js-preloader').preloadinator({
    minTime: 2000,
    scroll: false,
    animation: 'fadeOut',
    animationDuration: 400,
    afterDisableScroll: function() { 
      alert('afterDisableScroll'); 
      window.location.href= 'https://www.google.com'
    },
    afterEnableScroll: function() {alert('afterEnableScroll')},
    afterRemovePreloader: function() {alert('afterRemovePreloader')}
});
```

`afterDisableScroll, afterEnableScroll, afterRemovePreloader,` are the callbackback functions, which you can use.

I have added, `alert` and `window.location.href` to redirect the page to **google.com**, so you can use any of the 3 functions available according to your need.

Comment: That did not fix it for me. It's still just stock on loading

Comment: I downloaded the demo, and used it on my local, it works fine for me, please can you share the file and what you are trying to change in the code?

Comment: is there anyway I can send it to you privately? I don't want to share it publicly

Comment: you can remove the sensitive information and share it, I am not sure of any methods, try jsfiddle and share it

Comment: Btw make sure you are loading jquery before loading dist/js/jquery.preloadinator.min.js file

Comment: compare and check what you might be missing!

Comment: I think it's something to do with including jquery, when I remove it from jsfiddle I get the same error I'm having on my browser which is the page stuck on loading but when I put it back on it works fine. I even used the same cdn url that I used on my code, weird.